# Alsa Driver Ubuntu Compiler error when running 'configure' for installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation, configure, alsa

When running configure in alsa driver installation, I get the error like this

```
checking for GCC version... ./configure: eval: line 3547: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./configure: eval: line 3547: `my_compiler_version=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)'
```

How to solve this? I check the given line number, It is taking value from an environment variable or some other variable.

When I ran the variable like, `echo <name_of_the_variable>` there was no output.

Answer (score 0):

The `alsa-driver` package is outdated.

The sound drivers are part of the kernel. To update or recompile them, update or recompile the kernel.